# Joomla 2.53 and Joomla 3.02 in XAMPP 1.8

Tags: xampp, joomla2.5

Installed Joomla 3.02 and XAMPP 1.81 succesfully on a localhost to try it out. However I still want to work with Joomla 2.53 while I am trying to get to grips with Joomla version 3. I get problems with the database when I want to install Joomla 2.53 in this XAMPP 1.81. Can Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.02 not co-run in the same XAMPP 1.81 ?

Answer (score 1):

They run fine on the same XAMPP installation. But of course they can't use the same database.

Go to localhost/phpmyadmin/ and create a database for each Joomla! installation. For example one named Joomla25 and one Joomla30.
During Joomla! installation, you then set the corresponsing database and Joomla! will create the needed tables within the specified database.

Also make sure you use the latest Joomla! versions, which are Joomla! 2.5.9 and Joomla! 3.0.3.

Comment: What do you mean they can't use the same database? Of course they can! But it's cleaner to use 2 separate databases. +1 for the suggestion of using updated versions.

Comment: You're right, they can use the same database if they use a different table prefix. I didn't think of that as I always use different databases.